# Jquery: How to affect parent WHILE not children?

Tags: jquery, selector, parent, children

Is there a way to not affect children that are inside a parent when the parent is being changed?

```
<p>old text <a class="mylink">old link text</a></p>

$("a.mylink").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().text("new text for p");
        $(this).text("new link text for a");
    });
});
```

The above seems to get rid of the link text completely. I'd basically like to be able to change both texts when the click happens.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a JQuery solution, but this works:

```
$("a.mylink").click(function() {
    $(this)[0].previousSibling.nodeValue = "new text for p";
    $(this).text("new link text for a");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this trick. It works

```
 $("a.mylink").click(function() {
       $(this).parent().html("new text for p" + $(this).text("new link text for a").html());
   });
```